# how to resize an image to a fit within max width and max height?

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing

I have a CI image upload form, and I want to make sure the images I upload will fit in a given rectangle. If they are too big - I want to downsize them. If they fit within that rectangle - I don't need resizing.

I know CI supports max-height and max-width (as a limitation on how big the uploaded images can be), and it supports resize, but I couldn't find how to resize the image to a set max-height and max-width (while maintining the ratio).

Comment: Question is not clear. Want to downsize not to resize?

Comment: As I said in my question, I want to downsize them only if they are too big. If they are not wider than my max width and not taller than my max height, I don't need to resize them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it was easy enough, as expected from CI (-:

When using `$this->image_lib->resize()`, you set the desired width & height. If you also set maintain_ratio to true, the new image will be resized to the closest possible values of your set width & height, while preserving the original aspect ratio.

So this is the code I used, after uploading the image:

```
$file_data = $this->upload->data();

$max_height = 115;
$max_width = 225;
if ($file_data['image_width']>$max_width || $file_data['image_height']>$max_height)
{
    $configResize = array(
                        'source_image' => $file_data['full_path'],
                        'width' => $max_width,
                        'height' => $max_height,
                        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE
                );

      $this->load->library('image_lib',$configResize);
      $this->image_lib->resize())  
 }
```

Comment: I wonder if codeigniter doesn't automatically compare image width/height to max width/height before doing the resize ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the height and width you would like the resized image to be.  For example:

1. Suppose your input image is 1200x1000 and you want your resized image to be 300x200.
2. Find the size ratios 1200/1000=1.2 and 300/200=1.5.
3. If the original ratio is larger than the targeted resized size ratio you want to match the width, else you want to math the height.  In this case we want to match the height.
4. Find the scale factor to change the image to the target size.  Scale factor is 200/1000=0.2.
5. Use the scale factor to find the new size 1200x1000 scaled by 0.2 (1200*0.2 and 1000*0.2) = 240x200.
6. Resize the image to 240x200 as it is your best fit for the 300x200 box.

Take from the website provided by Silviu G http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'originalImage.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 240;
    $config['height'] = 200;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out the calculation is not needed, because CI does it automatically, if you set `$config['maintain_ratio'] =TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way to handle this is through CSS (in conjunction with the CI image manipulation library for resizing):

```
    .media img{
        max-width:100px;
        max-height:100px;
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you - do you mean I should handle that after I upload the image, when displaying the uploaded image on my site?

Comment: You'd use the image manipulation class to set its width/height upon upload (that is effectively the maximum width/height you want uploaded images to be); the CSS gives you another tool (after upload), to force your images to have a given maximum width/height. Alternatively, you could check the images width/height upon upload and use an `if/else`check to determine whether or not the image should be resized or not. The former method (with CSS) gives you more flexibility, should your design ever change and images are required to be shown bigger or smaller.

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about the CSS idea. might be enough for now. But if not - how can I check the image width/height upon upload?

Comment: `$this->upload->data()`gives you an array of information regarding the uploaded image, including width/height: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Image Manipulation Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/images.html) form CI

Comment: But how do I set a max height and max width with that class? From what I understand, it only supports *set* width and *set* height.

Comment: I believe you can _force_ the image to be resized to certain dimensions, but the default behaviour is to have the image **fit** in the indicated dimension(s). Just what you want to do -- oh wait, you already found that on yourself. Good job, and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: The link is no more working ... 404

Comment: I posted that answer roughly nine years ago. I've updated the link to point to the **current** documentation. As for how to use it, there are examples there.